# Simplemodal ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, simplemodal

i have this function roadajax() which appends data to a .modal-content

```
$(".modal-content").append("text here");
```

this .modal-content is set to display:none;

then i add OnClick to element , so when i click that element it opens a modal on .modal-content and show me its content on the modal

```
$(document).on("click", ".element", function() {
    // remove the current active element
    $(".element").removeClass("active-element");
    // add active class on the current element
    $(this).addClass("active-element");
    curitem = $(this).attr("id");
    roadajax(); // assigns content to .modal-content
    // showing the current element modal
    $(".active-element .modal-content").modal();
});
```

when i click on .element event handler fires up and i see modal ! but no data what so ever 
so i inspected it using firebug ..

if i removed .modal() call from my event handler normal logic happens and .modal-content is populated by raodajax()
but if i re-added .modal() call .. roadajax() seems to not be able to load data into .modal-content .. some kind of a race condition

i want to know how i can show my data into modal .. is there is any other way ?

Comment: Which library have you use for this "$(".active-element .modal-content").modal();"

Comment: jquery jquerysimple-modal http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ this one

Comment: setTimeout(function(){$(".active-element .modal-content").modal();}, 1000) 
here is how i solved it

Comment: Timeout is not every browser has same to load content. so, it is not much useful and acceptable.

Comment: Try to use this with Ajax demo:
https://github.com/plasm/simplemodal/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use direct Ajax Model by placing this syntax:

e.g.

```
function roadajax() {
     // This is In-built Ajax Functionality Provide by SimpleModel
     $('.modal-content').load('http://yoursite.com/page.html').modal();
}
```

This will automatically Load your page inside Model.

Comment: the problem is , it's an XML page and it needs parsing and formatting into HTML ,, can i do that ?

Comment: Share your Ajax Code I will check.
Actually In your Ajax Success/Done Portion whatever the Response will return You should first Prepare HTML Output and Load That Output In to Your Model.

Comment: there you go man , http://pastebin.com/6Tgf5kfx .. i should hint that it is not my code .. i am just working on it and it's disgusting